# cake php 2.9 login method not working

Tags: php, cakephp

i am new to cake php 2.9 , i have a small issue in login function my codes in view and login controller are as follows

```
 public function login() {

            if($this->request->is('post')) {
                if($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or Password!');
                }
            }

        }
```

and my view/users/login file codes are

## Log In

```
<?php 

    echo $this->form->create('User');
    echo $this->form->input('user_name');
    echo $this->form->input('password');
    echo $this->form->end('login');

    ?>
```

DB name is Users, Model class name User, 
DB columns name = user_name and password

Thank you

Comment: Please share your auth component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your AppController.php has proper setup for this.

```
// app/Controller/AppController.php
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                  'username' => 'user_name', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                  'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here most important is

```
'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array(
          'username' => 'user_name', // important!!!!
          'password' => 'password' 
        )
    )
)
```

Details check [Configuring Authentication handlers](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: This is the solution , Thankyou

Comment: @HassamAliQazalbash Then you should accept the answer

Comment: can you also tell me how can i create default value ?

 $this->request->data['Project']['visible'] = 2;    like this is not working

Comment: You can set default database value or you can set it before save

Comment: i am using this but its now working kindly have a look thanks , 


'if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Project->create();
             $this->request->data['Project']['visible'] = 2;
            if ($this->Project->save($this->request->data))'